# GoogleMaps.TimeZone.Query LatLng returning incorrect timeoffset

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3, timezone

When I attempt to get the time offset from Amsterdam, using GoogleMaps.TimeZone.Query, it says that it 19 minutes ahead instead of 1 hour. Why would this be? Any Ideas?

Here is the response:

```
Offset: 0.0
RawOffSet: 1172.0
Status: OK
StatusStr: "OK"
TimeZoneId: "Europe/Amsterdam"
TimeZoneName: "GMT+00:19:32"
```

Here is my code below:

```
var geocodeRequest = new GeocodingRequest()
{
    Address = address
};
var geocodeResponse = GoogleMaps.Geocode.Query(geocodeRequest);

var responseResult = geocodeResponse.Results.FirstOrDefault();
if (responseResult != null)
{
    var timezoneResult = GoogleMaps.TimeZone.Query(
        new TimeZoneRequest
        {
            Sensor = false, 
            Language = user.UserProfile.Culture, 
            Location = responseResult.Geometry.Location
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Added another parameter called timestamp which is now to universal time

var timezoneResult = GoogleMaps.TimeZone.Query(new TimeZoneRequest{Sensor =false, Language = user.UserProfile.Culture, Location = responseResult.Geometry.Location,TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()});

This seems to have solved the problem.